# Is there any way to run node script in firebase?

Tags: ios, node.js, swift, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have a question about firebase function. I can generate json data with swift in my app and I have to send it to node and run that node script for send these datas to different server. This server can't communicate with swift so I have to run that node script. 
If I can write this json data on firebase real time database,  can my firebase cloud function listen and run node script? 
Please help me I in very bad situation.

Comment: "can my firebase cloud function listen and run node script" -> can you please elaborate a bit? Do you mean **running** some JavaScript code as you would do in node.js

Comment: @RenaudTarnec Yes I want to ask that sorry for my eng. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: So you will write the JSON to the Relatime Database and you want the Cloud Function to get this JSON and run some JavaScript (or TypeScript) code as you would do in Node.js in order to "treat" this JSON. Thanks to confirm.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec Yes its completely correct. Thanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cloud Functions currently support Node.js versions 8 and 10 (Node.js 10 runtime being currently in beta).

So indeed, you can very well run some JavaScript (or TypeScript) code in Cloud Functions, as you would do in Node.js.

I understand that your requirement is as follows:

> I want to save some JSON to the Realtime Database, and have the
>   Cloud Function **detecting** this new addition to the Realtime
>   Database and do something with this JSON.

This is exactly what does a Cloud Function triggered by a background event in the Realtime Database, as explained [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events) in the doc.

The Cloud Function can detect a change/event in the Realtime Database (addition, modification or deletion), then can get the value that was changed (in your case the JSON that was added at a specific node) and can use it to do "something", like writing to a new node in the database or composing a message to send via FCM, or deleting unused Firebase accounts listed in the JSON, or calling an API exposed by a server on the internet, etc, etc... the possibilities are nearly endless, as explained [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases#perform_sanitization_and_maintenance) in the doc.

---

To start with Cloud Functions, I would suggest to read the [Get Started](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started) section, to watch the [video series](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series) (a must!) and try the [Cloud Functions codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-cloud-functions/#0). Good luck and do not hesitate to ask new questions if you encounter any problem!

Comment: Thank yo so much. I want to ask something too I am new at programming so I need some sample code for make it more clear. Can you have one?

Comment: Have a look at the update: while you were writing your comment I was adding a section in my answer on how to start. In particular, you should try the Cloud Functions codelab.